# Viewing answer 1 of 0

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I just answered my own question, and am now viewing answer 1 of 0 - doesn't seem right!

Note this is both in the title bar, and the big bold "0 answers" line - unfortunately I can't add red freehand circles on the app...

[image: screenshot]

Comment: *I can't add red freehand circles*. You could with [Skitch](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/skitch-snap.-mark-up.-send./id490505997?mt=8); that's what I use when needing to do freehand circles on iOS..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Haha, thank you. For next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found this a little while back; this bug has been fixed in beta version  1.2.0.168, and the fix will be available in the next Appstore update.

The issue had to do with how we keep track of the answers in the app – the rendered answers are stored separately from the answers we retrieve from the API. When a new answer was added, we would append it to the rendered ones. However, the logic that calculates "answer x of y" and "x answers" was still referring to the API answers, which were out of date. This has been rectified.

Comment: I was just going through this problem when I noticed your changes would have already fixed it. :)

Comment: Great - sounds good! Is the beta app still publicly available, or just internal now? I found some relevant meta posts, but they're 7 months old or so. (The one with a Google form?) I'll get signed up if it's still active, save this happening again!

Comment: @Chris yes, the Beta up is still updated regularly. It gets fixes much more quickly than the Appstore.

Comment: Great, thanks. Just signed up.

Comment: Looks like it's back: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246515/off-by-one-error

Comment: And [it's still back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265934/how-many-questions-are-there)..