# Off by one error

Tags: bug, ios-app

When I post an answer from the iOS app, it takes me back to the question page... Where, more often than not, my new answer is listed right below a banner that says "0 answers".

Using pull to refresh updates the answer count. Is the app not trying to check the answer count after posting, or maybe it is but it's hitting a race condition?

Comment: Looks like a return of [an already fixed bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246045/viewing-answer-1-of-0).

Comment: This has been found and fixed, the fix will be available with the next Appstore update.