# How many answers are there?

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Apparently I can't count... how many answers are there?

> [image: Wrong]

The view in the iOS app shows 0 answers after posting the first answer. After a manual refresh it does show the right count.

Can this be fixed please?

---

- App Version: 1.3.2.229
- Device: iPhone7,2
- OS Version: Version 8.4.1 (Build 12H321)

Comment: Looks like the return of [this fixed bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246045/viewing-answer-1-of-0).

Comment: Yeah, this bug just keeps returning, or maybe different variations of it. And no worry, happens to the best of us. :-D

Comment: Wait.... you got iPhone 7 before it was released for sale?

Comment: @sha I think I broke a NDA now... ;)

Comment: lol, hurry hide your tracks!

Comment: Too late. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/265946/245360

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

When a new answer is added, it gets appended to the canonical questions data like so:

```
NSArray *storeAnswers = self.questionStore.questionData.answers;
if (![[storeAnswers valueForKeyPath:@"answerId"] containsObject:@(answer.answerId)]){
    self.questionStore.questionData.answers = [storeAnswers arrayByAddingObject:answer];
}
```

The problem is that if the server returns `null` for the empty answers array (which it can and does do) and the programming language treats `null + answer` as `null`, that answer just disappears.

The solution is:

```
NSArray *storeAnswers = self.questionStore.questionData.answers ?: @[];
if (![[storeAnswers valueForKeyPath:@"answerId"] containsObject:@(answer.answerId)]){
    self.questionStore.questionData.answers = [storeAnswers arrayByAddingObject:answer];
}
```

The root cause is *probably* that I used to convert null values to arrays when I was doing `Array<Dictionary>` to `Array<Answer>` and now I don't.

Comment: Thanks for fixing and the explanation!